# Getting an additional number when outputting numbers of a String

Tags: java, arrays, println

I have a rather simple question, yet I'm puzzled as to why this is happening: The following chunk of code is a method that returns a numeric string that originally had numbers and/or special characters. Here:

```
public static int[] toNumArray (String string) {
    int[] x = new int[countNums(string)];
     int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
            //System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
            x[j] = Character.digit(string.charAt(i), 10);
            j++;
        }

    }

    return x;
}
```

Now, I understand this method is, in fact, doing its job. The problem I'm having is outputting the results while calling a printing method, which is:

```
public static void printArray(int[] nums) {
  for( int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i ) {
     System.out.print( nums[i] + ", ");

  }
  int last = nums.length - 1;
  System.out.println( nums[last] );
    System.out.println();
}
```

When I call those methods in Main, I get an additional number which happens to always be the last number. Here:

```
    String s = "12345abc";
    printArray(toNumArray(s));
```

I get

*1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **5***

Why does this happen? I passed all test cases successfully per se, but this is clearly not right.

Comment: Have you traced through its execution with a debugger? Put a breakpoint on your for loop in `toNumArray` and step through the iterations.

Comment: What is `countNums` in your code?

Comment: @SergeiSirik That's another method I coded out so I could know for sure how many elements there are in a given string.

Comment: @StephenP Not yet! I will soon though. I don't know how to use the debugger feature yet, to be honest with you.

Comment: @CarlosA.Blanco, so provide the code for it, cause it can contain mistakes as well.

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println( nums[last] );` does? Wouldn't that print the last number *again*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code in the loop

```
for( int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i ) {
    System.out.print( nums[i] + ", ");
}
```

you'll print all numbers in your array (from 1 to 5)

When you exit by this loop you have these lines:

```
int last = nums.length - 1;
System.out.println( nums[last] );
```

Here you'll print the last element of your array (number 5) but you have used in the for loop the print so you remain on the same line.

So you'll have:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5
```

In this way: by your loop `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,`

By the last println (out the for loop): `5`

**EDIT** After comment:

To remove the last comma you can resolve as follow:

In the for loop you must use a variable defined as follow:

```
String res = "";
for( int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i ) {
    res += nums[i] + ", ";
}
```

Out of the for loop:

```
res = res.substring(0, res.length - 1);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: I see where you coming from! However, the reason why I added that the line containing "int last[...]", is because I don't want the last digit to be displayed with a comma right next to it. In other words, I'd like the last number to have a comma to its left and not its right. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in your `printArray(int[] nums)` method which prints last digit one more time:

```
int last = nums.length - 1;
System.out.println( nums[last] );
System.out.println();
```

Comment: I got you. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays count from 0.

So for a 5 digit array, the indexes are 0 1 2 3 4.

You see that 4 is already i < nums.length. Set it to nums.length - 1, to omit the trailing colon.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your input!